# Python For Loop includes the end of the range

Tags: python, range

I'm on checkio.org trying to solve this problem:

You are given a two or more digits number N. For this mission, you should find the smallest positive number of X, such that the product of its digits is equal to N. If X does not exist, then return 0.
Let's examine the example. N = 20. We can factorize this number as 2*10, but 10 is not a digit. Also we can factorize it as 4*5 or 2*2*5. The smallest number for 2*2*5 is 225, for 4*5 -- 45. So we select 45.

I've created the recursive function that factorizes an integer and I'm passing the factoredList into another recursive function called "groupIt" to find the lowest integer that's the product of the factored integers.

Here's the function:

```
def groupIt(digits):
    tempList = []
    if len(digits)>1:
        for z in range(0,len(digits)-1):
            if digits[z]*digits[z+1]>=10:
                toStore=""
                for k in range(0,len(digits)):
                    toStore+=str(digits[k])
                return int(toStore)
            else:
                digits.append(digits.pop(z+1)*digits.pop(z))
                digits.sort()
                tempList.append(groupIt(digits))
    else:
        return digits[0]
    tempList.sort()
    return tempList[0]
```

For an integer '20', the factored list is 2 x 2 x 5. When I recursively call groupIt on [4,5], "len(digits)-1" = 1, so z goes from range (0,1).

As I understand it, z should only be 0, since it wouldn't include the last integer in the range, but z does eventually go to 1 in the same for-loop for [4,5].

If I replace "for z in range(0,len(digits)-1)" with "for z in range(0,1)," the code works, so the problem does appear to be isolated there.

Thoughts?

Comment: Please consider using the preferred `for digit in digits:` rather than `for z in range(0, len(digits)-1):`

Comment: Does this work if I only want to iterate len(digits)-1 times?

Comment: When I try to run your code with a `groupIt('20')` I get a `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'` for the line `if digits[z]*digits[z+1]>=10:`.

Comment: `for digit in digits[:-1]`

Comment: Ah, you need to run it with groupIt([2,2,5]). I have a separate, not-included function that breaks "20" down to [2,2,5].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are mutating `digits` while you try to iterate over it (using `.pop`) to pass to the recursive call - the error isn't in the recursive call, it's when you return to the outer call and try to move to the next `z`. You should make a *copy* of digits (e.g. using `digits[:]`) and alter that instead:

```
else:
    digits_mod = digits[:]
    digits_mod.append(digits_mod.pop(z+1) * digits_mod.pop(z))
    digits_mod.sort()
    tempList.append(groupIt(digits_mod))
```

However, this modification still doesn't allow the code to work for e.g. `groupIt([2, 2, 3, 5])`, which returns `2235` not `256`.

Instead. I suggest making a list at the top level and passing it down, allowing it to be modified at all levels:

```
def groupIt(digits, output=None):
    if output is None:
        output = []
    if len(digits)>1:
        for z in range(0,len(digits)-1):
            if digits[z]*digits[z+1]>=10:
                toStore=""
                for k in range(0,len(digits)):
                    toStore+=str(digits[k])
                output.append(int(toStore)) # note storage here
            else:
                digits_mod = digits[:]
                digits_mod.append(digits_mod.pop(z+1) * digits_mod.pop(z))
                digits_mod.sort()
                groupIt(digits_mod, output) # note call here
    else:
        return digits[0] # still need this for single digit case
    return min(output)
```

Now the recursive calls ignore the `return` value, allowing the minimum of the final, complete `output` to be returned to whatever called `groupIt` in the first place.

I get, for example:

```
>>> groupIt([2, 2, 3, 5])
256
```

(`output == [345, 345, 256, 256, 2235]` before returning).

---

A neater version of the same logic:

```
def groupIt(lst, out=None):
    if out is None:
        out = set()
    out.add(int("".join(map(str, sorted(lst)))))
    if len(lst) > 1:
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            n = lst[i] * lst[i+1]
            if n < 10:
                groups(lst[:i] + [n] + lst[i+2:], out)
    return min(out)
```

Comment: Ah, I have to be careful what I mutate. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I have just added a neater version of the same logic.